# Pyplot won't stop showing decimal percentages of X and Y axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use pyplot to do linear modeling, and I've run across a problem. When I make a plot of the data, pyplot wants to put decimal percentages along the X and Y axis. I've tried a few different things to make it go away. I want to keep some tick labels, so I've tried various methods of adding my own tick labels, and that works, however, it still prints its own tick labels on top.

So at the origin it says 0.0, then a fifth of the way along the axis it says 0.2, so on until the end of the axis it says 1.0.

Example image of the problem:
[image: Example image of the problem]

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
big_plot = fig.add_subplot(111)
data_plot = fig.add_subplot(211)
residual_plot = fig.add_subplot(212)
data_plot.plot(x,y,'ro')
data_plot.errorbar(x,model,sigma)
residual_plot.plot(x,residuals,'b*')
data_plot.set_title("Data")
data_plot.set_ylabel(y_label)
residual_plot.set_title("Residuals")
residual_plot.set_ylabel("Residual Value")
big_plot.set_xlabel(x_label)
plt.show()
```

Does anyone know how to clear those tick labels and add my own? Thank you.

Comment: Get rid of `big_plot` entirely. This is an empty plot that it creating the axis labels you don't want. Set the xlabel on `data_plot` to label the axis.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you are creating three plots, but only plotting data on two of them. The `big_plot` is axis is plotted with the default tick marks and it is the source of the extra tick marks that you don't want.

Instead, just remove this axis and label the bottom x-axis by assigning the label to `data_plot`.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
data_plot = fig.add_subplot(211)
residual_plot = fig.add_subplot(212)
data_plot.plot(x,y,'ro')
data_plot.errorbar(x,model,sigma)
residual_plot.plot(x,residuals,'b*')
data_plot.set_title("Data")
data_plot.set_ylabel(y_label)
residual_plot.set_title("Residuals")
residual_plot.set_ylabel("Residual Value")
data_plot.set_xlabel(x_label)
plt.show()
```